Making an AJAX call to a LocalHost from my main web site
I have a web page on my main web site ( that has an SSL certificate) and am  trying to make an AJAX call to my local server  (on my local machine with no SSL certificate.) Here is an extract of the code I am using :
function getSomeData (){
    
    $.ajax({
      
      url: 'http://?.?.?.?:2042/somefolder/somephp.php',
      type: "POST",
      async:false,
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 3000,
      data: {
        apram:someparam
      },
      success: function (res) {
      console.log(res)
        if (res){
          console.log(res)
        }
      },// Success
      timeout: 4000, // sets timeout to 3 seconds
      error: function (res) {
        console.log(res)
        alert('Errorconnecting to the server')
      }
        return something;
    });
   

  }

I get a POST error "NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':...."
the error comes back as .. net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
I have just changed some details (ip address etc) but otherwise the code is correct.
Am I getting this error because I am making a request from a secure site to a non-secure (SSL) location ?
Thanks
Paul.


Am I getting this error because I am making a request from a secure site to a non-secure (SSL) location

The short answer is: no.
If you are using HTTP, there is no encryption in the request. So whether or not your process is a site that uses inbound SSL is not a factor. You can turn it off and try it to confirm.
What is really going on? A couple possibilities. You should manually send the request from curl or wget with verbose mode, and also look at the receiving server's logs.
Since you are using HTTP, you can also use telnet, if you are feeling very hands-on.
